How to solve the issue , Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first
I have react jwplayer in one of my component , when I go directly using url, and play the video, so when I tried to pause it gives me error

Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.
and then I am not able to pause the video as well.
here is code for the react jwplayer

  return (
    <div
      className={classNames(classes.jwplayerWrapper, "jwplayerWrapper")}
      data-testid="jwplayerContainer"
    >
      {jwplayerVideo.videoUrl && (
        <ReactJWPlayer
          className={classes.jwplayerContainer}
          id="jwplayerRender"
          playerId={config.jwplayer.playerId}
          playerScript="https://cdn.jwplayer.com/libraries/TywNSfie.js"
          playlist={getJwPlayerList(
            jwplayerVideo.videoUrl,
            jwplayerVideo.isLiveStreaming,
            jwplayerVideo.tracks,
            jwplayerVideo.showTranscoding
          )}
          onReady={onJwplayerReady}
          onEnterFullScreen={onEnterFullScreen}
          onExitFullScreen={onExitFullScreen}
          customProps={{
            floating: { dismissible: true },
            plugins: getPlugIns(
              jwplayerVideo.isLiveStreaming,
              jwplayerVideo.bookmark
            ),
          }}
          ref={playerRef}
          autoplay={true}
        />
      )}
      <div className="refClick"></div>
    </div>
  );

I do not want to mute the video. Video play on page load is the requirement
